# Utilizing a Right and Left Outer Joins in same SELECT

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to better build my SQL Development skill set.  Where I work currently most all the data fits into a hierarchy and we almost always start with the top most element to work our way "down".  This results in really only needing to use `INNER` and `LEFT OUTER` joins for the various queries.

I am hoping to get some guidance on a situation where I might need to use a `RIGHT OUTER` and a `LEFT OUTER` JOIN in the same query.

Referencing a previous question on StackOverflow [What is the difference between Left, Right, Outer and Inner Joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins) I understand what a `RIGHT OUTER` and a `LEFT OUTER` JOIN is, however all problems I have been asked to solve, could be solved using only `INNER` and `LEFT OUTER` joins.

EDIT:

I did find that this is basically a duplicate of a previous StackOverflow question [When or why would you use a right outer join instead of left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436345/when-or-why-would-you-use-a-right-outer-join-instead-of-left).  It would appear that in general there is a consensus that

1. Most all queries using a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` can be converted into an
   `INNER` and `LEFT OUTER` version.
2. There are some benefits for
       read-ability formatting or organizational processes which might
       require using a `RIGHT OUTER` instead of a `LEFT OUTER`.

There is also an answer on that question which details a particular situation where you would `INNER JOIN` a group of tables together and then `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` to find where the "right" table has records in the whole `INNER JOIN`'ed subset.  I think this can be accomplished with an `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` version it would just require some work.

Comment: You should describe the *"situation where I might need to use a `RIGHT OUTER` and a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in the same query"*.

Comment: @MDCCL That is what the question is. Can we provide guidance on when this would ever be required?

Comment: @MartinSmith So that means that the OP wants someone to describe such a situation, that is, provide an example? I'm interpreting the issue as something like *"I'm involved in a situation where I might need to use a `RIGHT OUTER`... in the same query, so I want guidance on it"*, but it looks like you are understanding the question correctly.

Comment: @kirk Could you confirm Martin's interpretation?

Comment: Martin does have the correct interpretation, however I can see how my phrasing would indicate the version that MDCCL came to.  I apologize for the poor phrasing.  I don't currently have a situation where I might need both.  I am looking for an example where I might so that I can improve my skillset.  And prevent myself from trying to solve all problems one way.  The whole idea of "if you are a hammer, everything looks like a nail".

Comment: Eric Darling posted this recently which also answers the question: https://erikdarling.com/blog/#:~:text=there%20is%20no%20natural%20reason%20to%20ever%20use%20a%20right%20join%2C%20that%20isn%E2%80%99t%20better%20logically%20expressed%20in%20a%20different%20way. His general recommendation is you don't need a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In practice you never *need* to use a RIGHT JOIN, and I can't think of a scenario where I would *want* to.

Any query involving RIGHT JOINs that can't be trivially transformed into a query using only LEFT JOINs should probably be burned with fire.

You can solve almost any problem using a pipeline of CTEs, each of which uses 0 or more INNER JOINs followed by 0 or more LEFT JOINs.

Comment: I hit one once a long time ago; some horrible nasty combination of RIGHT JOIN and NOT IN clauses that was not transformable. I forget exactly what the concoction was. Incidentally, SQL server can't do a right loop join but must hash join the thing.

Comment: Not to worry, it's not in production anymore (if it ever was).